# Could not store data to custom user model from django shell

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is custom user model class

```
class User(AbstractUser, BaseUserManager):

    username=None

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_by =models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser= models.BooleanField(default=False)

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['password']

    objects = ContentManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

This is my `manager.py` for User model

```
class ContentManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations=True

    def create_user(self, email,password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Email must be set")
    
    
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,**extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)

        return user

    def create_super_user (self,email, password,name, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_admin',True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser',True)  
        return self.create_user(email,password,**extra_fields)
```

The problem is when I wanted to create the user from django shell by following method.

```
python manage.py shell
from api.models import Users
user = User.objects.create_user(name="roshan",email="example@example.com",password="password")
```

Even if put some data in `name` field, it is showing `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'name' cannot be null")` error.

I couldn't figure out where I went wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User` class should not inherit from `BaseUserManager` (only the manager should), E.g.,

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
```

See [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) in the django documentation for more details.

With `class User(AbstractUser, BaseUserManager)`, eventually the name was being overwritten (by `BaseManager`).